# Set Precision for NSNumber value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am having an issue with an NSNumber variable "num" that is currently containing 0.522000003606

I looked up several other issues on stackoverflow with others having the same issue but nothing. My project is currently using ARC so I think some features are unavailable, that is, unless I disallow ARC within the class I am currently wanting to set the precision of the NSNumber.

I understand NSNumberFormatter is the basic setPrecision class function I must use but I am having issues....

Everytime i use NSNumberFormatter, it spits back NULL!!!

```
nowValue = [now objectForKey:@"value"]; // This is what IM ACTUALLY DOING!!!
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setFormatWidth:2];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

I feel like this is SOOO trivial! Can anyone give an amateur programmer some advise ? :)

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm doing now, using an NSDecimal rather than NSNumber. "Now" is a large dictionary object and nowValue is a copy of num.

```
nowValue = (__bridge NSDecimal *)([now objectForKey:@"value"]);
```

Comment: Show us the code where you NSLog the value of "num" going in.

Comment: NSDecimal is a structure, not an object, so now I'm really really confused. Update your question with a real example. Start with a NSNumber initialized to 0.522000003606, then the formatter stuff, then the output that is NOT what you want it to be, and tell us what you want the exact string to look like.

Comment: What type of object does `[now objectForKey:@"value"]` actually return? Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [[now objectForKey:@"value"] class]`? - Note that any casting or bridging does not change the object at all and therefore does not help.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [[now objectForKey:@"value"] class] returns a __NSCFString object.

Comment: So Bruno had it right, even though he deleted his answer.  JSON is returning a string, not a numeric value -- NSString, not NSNumber.  (If you look at the JSON source you will see that the number is surrounded with quotes, making it a string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!..... Thanks for everyones input but yea.... it was a string. Martin R, thanks for you debugging code. And understanding _NSCFString is really just a wrapper for an NSString but they were mainly the same.

Here was my solution...

```
nowValue outputs : 24.14295959472

nowValue = [now objectForKey:@"value"];
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * nowNum = [f numberFromString:nowValue];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
nowValueFormatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:nowNum];

nowNum outputs : 24.14
```

Comment: I plan on having a formatter function to make this more efficient because apparently using formatter classes is VERY inefficient.... Within the function, I will include static variables to allow formatter objects not to be reallocated and take up lots of memory