# NSNumber with representative number ( .0 ) not in NSString format

Tags: ios, nsnumber

Hi everyone,

I'm working with a private API and I need to send integer and double values.

For integers, I don't have any problem, I convert the integer to NSNumber and everything works fine.

But with double with no decimal numbers ( 46 for instance ) my request is rejected because the server sees an integer where there should be a double.

My sys admin told me to send round double value with ".0", so if I want to send the double 46, I have to send 46.0.

The problem is that I can't send an NSString or the server will also reject my request ( it will see a string where there should be a double ).

So here is my question : is there a way to add representative numbers to NSNumbers ? So my double 46 would be NSNumber 46.0

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting precision of NSNumber http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900401/set-precision-for-nsnumber-value

Comment: What technology are you using?  It's not clear how the `NSNumber`s work and primitive types don't.  And BTW the server implementation is broken.

Comment: What do you mean by "technology" ?

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are initialising the NSNumber you should use

```
mynumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: myDoublevalue];
```

and when you want to send it to server try like

```
[mynumber doubleValue];
```

Comment: The problem is : I need to add that value in a dictionary, and that's impossible to do with a double

Comment: @Alexandre What do you mean? Do you use NSDictionary or some another dictionary implementation? It is also impossible to add int to a NSDictionary. Only NSNumber. And if you use NSNumber dictionary does not care what number is inside.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't explain myself really well. I'm using a NSDictionary and I store NSNumbers in it. But if I store `mynumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: myDoublevalue];` where `myDoublevalue = 63` then the server sees an int and not a double

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is: What do you use to create your NSNumber?

Using

```
NSNumber *intNumber = @(46);
```

Will give you an `NSNumber` that contains an `int`, whereas

```
NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:46];
```

should result in an `NSNumber` containing a `double` .

(You can check this by calling `[intNumber objCType]`, which will give "i" and `[doubleNumber objCType` will give "d")

The other problem you might experience is that you (or the API you use) uses some format conversion to JSON or something else.

Normal JSON converters will omit the `.0` and therefore you might get an error.

Therefore if you have access to the JSON (or what ever else format conversion you use, since you will never send an NSNumber to any server), you can fix it there.

Last point, if nothing helps with the two points above, you could think about adding a very small number, that will force a point, but won't make much of a difference in normal cases:

```
input = pow(2,log2(fabs(input))-50) //use 20 instead of 50 for float numbers!
NSNumber *result = @(input);
```

Comment: Just to add, converting a `double` of `46.0` to `NSNumber numberWithDouble` should automatically omit the `.0` leaving just `46`.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything @I'L'l? Still numberWithDouble will result in a different objCType than just using @(46) or numberWithInt.

The one I suggested will result in "d" instaedt of "i" and that is actually Alexandre's problem!

Comment: That's the problem actually, I tried to send it after having done `NSNumber numberWithDouble` but the server then sees an int

Comment: And how do you send it? Do you call a method of an objc framework or do you actually call an http api? For the http api, you can use my second suggestion, for the framework you will probably have to use the third 'dirty' option

Comment: @NilsZiehn: It's has to do with the question Nils, that's what.